# submit a form with jquery serialize() in Code igniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

im using CI in my  project and currently i have a issue. i  am sending a values through jquery serialize but the code is not working ...

here is the code.. in my view my form id is 'form' and button type is submit and id is 'btn' ..

```
    <script>

   $('#btn').click(function() {
       form = $("#form").serialize();

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php  echo site_url('categoryController/addCategory'); ?>",
       data: form,

       success: function(data){
           alert('Successful!);
       }

     });

     return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!

  });
```

Comment: what do mean by code is not working ? any errors ?

Comment: How is the code not working? Are there errors in the debugger console, is the url never called or is the data received at the url not as expected? Or something else?

Comment: the form is submitting with a refresh ..it is not going into ajax ..means you can say it is not catching the button id ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `event.preventDefault()` method to prevent the form from submitting.  It is also important to note that **there is an unterminated String literal** within the script.

```
  $('#btn').click(function(event) {
       form = $("#form").serialize();

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php  echo site_url('categoryController/addCategory'); ?>",
       data: form,

       success: function(data){
           alert('Successful!'); //Unterminated String literal fixed
       }

     });
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!

  });
```

Comment: Return false should act as both; preventDefault and stopPropagation

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Maybe it was the String literal causing the issue.

Comment: @kevin bowersox .. you rock man .. your code works ..thanks a lot

Comment: @user1972143 Glad I could help.  Please accept if it fixed your issue.

Comment: 1 more thing if u dont mind .. how can i after  getting successfull request empty the form fields ..like this form.val(""); am i right ?

Comment: `$("#form")[0].reset();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have event on form submit.

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
 form = $("#form").serialize();
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "<?php  echo site_url('categoryController/addCategory'); ?>",
   data: form,
   success: function(data){
       alert('Successful!);
  }
 });
 return false;
```

});